# How to solve partial Knight's Tour with special constraints

Tags: python, algorithm, chess, puzzle, knights-tour

Knight's tour problem described in the image here, with diagram.

[image: knight's tour variation]

```
A knight was initially located in a square labeled 1. It then proceeded to make a
series of moves, never re-visiting a square, and labeled the visited squares in
order. When the knight was finished, the labeled squares in each region of connected
squares had the same sum.

A short while later, many of the labels were erased. The remaining labels can be seen
above.

Complete the grid by re-entering the missing labels. The answer to this puzzle is
the sum of the squares of the largest label in each row of the completed grid, as in
the example.

[1]: E.g. the 14 and 33 are in different regions.
```

The picture explains it a lot more clearly, but in summary a Knight has gone around a 10 x 10 grid. The picture shows a 10 x 10 board that shows some positions in has been in, and at what point of its journey. You do not know which position the Knight started in, or how many movements it made.

The coloured groups on the board need to all sum to the same amount.

I’ve built a python solver, but it runs for ages - uses recursion. I’ve noted that the maximum sum of a group is 197, based on there being 100 squares and the smallest group is 2 adjacent squares.

My code at this link: https://pastebin.com/UMQn1HZa

```
import sys, numpy as np
 
fixedLocationsArray = [[ 12, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0],
                 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  5,  0,  23, 0],
                 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  8,  0,  0, 0],
                 [ 0,  0,  0,  14, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
                 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0],
                 [ 0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0, 0],
                 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  20,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
                 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  33,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
                 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0],
                 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  28]]
 
groupsArray = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,10, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,10, 0],
                  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9,10,10,10],
                  [2, 0, 1, 0, 0,11, 9, 9, 9, 9],
                  [2, 0, 0, 0,11,11,11,15,15, 9],
                  [2, 4, 4,14,11,12,12,15,15, 8],
                  [2, 3, 4,14,14,13,13,13,15, 8],
                  [2, 3, 5,14,16,16,16, 7, 7, 8],
                  [3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8]]
 
'''
Solver
- Noted that the maximum sum of a group is 197 since the group of only 2 can have the 100 filled and then 97 on return
'''
 
class KnightsTour:
    def __init__(self, width, height, fixedLocations, groupsArray):
        self.w = width
        self.h = height
        self.fixedLocationsArray = fixedLocations
        self.groupsArray = groupsArray
        self.npfixedLocationsArray = np.array(fixedLocations)
        self.npgroupsArray = np.array(groupsArray)
 
        self.board = [] # Contains the solution
        self.generate_board()
 
    def generate_board(self):
        """
        Creates a nested list to represent the game board
        """
        for i in range(self.h):
            self.board.append([0]*self.w)
 
    def print_board(self): # Prints out the final board solution
        print("  ")
        print("------")
        for elem in self.board:
            print(elem)
        print("------")
        print("  ")
 
    def generate_legal_moves(self, cur_pos, n):
        """
        Generates a list of legal moves for the knight to take next
        """
        possible_pos = []
        move_offsets = [(1, 2), (1, -2), (-1, 2), (-1, -2),
                        (2, 1), (2, -1), (-2, 1), (-2, -1)]
 
        locationOfNumberInFixed = [(ix,iy) for ix, row in enumerate(self.fixedLocationsArray) for iy, i in enumerate(row) if i == n+1]
        groupsizeIsNotExcessive = self.groupsNotExcessiveSize(self.board, self.groupsArray)
 
        for move in move_offsets:
            new_x = cur_pos[0] + move[0]
            new_y = cur_pos[1] + move[1]
            new_pos = (new_x, new_y)
 
            if groupsizeIsNotExcessive:
                if locationOfNumberInFixed:
                    print(f"This number {n+1} exists in the fixed grid at {locationOfNumberInFixed[0]}")
                    if locationOfNumberInFixed[0] == new_pos:
                        print(f"Next position is {new_pos} and matches location in fixed")
                        possible_pos.append((new_x, new_y))
                    else:
                        continue
                elif not locationOfNumberInFixed: # if the current index of move is not in table, then evaluate if it is a legal move
                    if (new_x >= self.h): # if it is out of height of the board, continue, don't app onto the list of possible moves
                        continue
                    elif (new_x < 0):
                        continue
                    elif (new_y >= self.w):
                        continue
                    elif (new_y < 0):
                        continue
                    else:
                        possible_pos.append((new_x, new_y))
            else:
                continue
        
        print(f"The legal moves for index {n} are {possible_pos}")
        print(f"The current board looks like:")
        self.print_board()
 
        return possible_pos
 
    def sort_lonely_neighbors(self, to_visit, n):
        """
        It is more efficient to visit the lonely neighbors first, 
        since these are at the edges of the chessboard and cannot 
        be reached easily if done later in the traversal
        """
        neighbor_list = self.generate_legal_moves(to_visit, n)
        empty_neighbours = []
 
        for neighbor in neighbor_list:
            np_value = self.board[neighbor[0]][neighbor[1]]
            if np_value == 0:
                empty_neighbours.append(neighbor)
 
        scores = []
        for empty in empty_neighbours:
            score = [empty, 0]
            moves = self.generate_legal_moves(empty, n)
            for m in moves:
                if self.board[m[0]][m[1]] == 0:
                    score[1] += 1
            scores.append(score)
 
        scores_sort = sorted(scores, key = lambda s: s[1])
        sorted_neighbours = [s[0] for s in scores_sort]
        return sorted_neighbours
 
    def groupby_perID_and_sum(self, board, groups):
 
        # Convert into numpy arrays
        npboard = np.array(board)
        npgroups = np.array(groups)
 
        # Get argsort indices, to be used to sort a and b in the next steps
        board_flattened = npboard.ravel()
        groups_flattened = npgroups.ravel()
 
        sidx = groups_flattened.argsort(kind='mergesort')
        board_sorted = board_flattened[sidx]
        groups_sorted = groups_flattened[sidx]
 
        # Get the group limit indices (start, stop of groups)
        cut_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,groups_sorted[1:] != groups_sorted[:-1],True])
 
        # Create cut indices for all unique IDs in b
        n = groups_sorted[-1]+2
        cut_idxe = np.full(n, cut_idx[-1], dtype=int)
 
        insert_idx = groups_sorted[cut_idx[:-1]]
        cut_idxe[insert_idx] = cut_idx[:-1]
        cut_idxe = np.minimum.accumulate(cut_idxe[::-1])[::-1]
 
        # Split input array with those start, stop ones
        arrayGroups = [board_sorted[i:j] for i,j in zip(cut_idxe[:-1],cut_idxe[1:])]
        arraySum = [np.sum(a) for a in arrayGroups]
 
        sumsInListSame = arraySum.count(arraySum[0]) == len(arraySum)
 
        return sumsInListSame
 
    def groupsNotExcessiveSize(self, board, groups):
        # Convert into numpy arrays
        npboard = np.array(board)
        npgroups = np.array(groups)
 
        # Get argsort indices, to be used to sort a and b in the next steps
        board_flattened = npboard.ravel()
        groups_flattened = npgroups.ravel()
 
        sidx = groups_flattened.argsort(kind='mergesort')
        board_sorted = board_flattened[sidx]
        groups_sorted = groups_flattened[sidx]
 
        # Get the group limit indices (start, stop of groups)
        cut_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,groups_sorted[1:] != groups_sorted[:-1],True])
 
        # Create cut indices for all unique IDs in b
        n = groups_sorted[-1]+2
        cut_idxe = np.full(n, cut_idx[-1], dtype=int)
 
        insert_idx = groups_sorted[cut_idx[:-1]]
        cut_idxe[insert_idx] = cut_idx[:-1]
        cut_idxe = np.minimum.accumulate(cut_idxe[::-1])[::-1]
 
        # Split input array with those start, stop ones
        arrayGroups = [board_sorted[i:j] for i,j in zip(cut_idxe[:-1],cut_idxe[1:])]
        arraySum = [np.sum(a) for a in arrayGroups]
        print(arraySum)
 
        # Check if either groups aren't too large
        groupSizeNotExcessive = all(sum <= 197 for sum in arraySum)
 
        return groupSizeNotExcessive
    
    def tour(self, n, path, to_visit):
        """
        Recursive definition of knights tour. Inputs are as follows:
        n = current depth of search tree
        path = current path taken
        to_visit = node to visit, i.e. the coordinate
        """
        self.board[to_visit[0]][to_visit[1]] = n # This writes the number on the grid
        path.append(to_visit) #append the newest vertex to the current point
        print(f"Added {n}")
        print(f"For {n+1} visiting: ", to_visit)
 
 
        if self.groupby_perID_and_sum(self.board, self.npgroupsArray): #if all areas sum
            self.print_board()
            print(path)
            print("Done! All areas sum equal")
            sys.exit(1)
 
        else:
            sorted_neighbours = self.sort_lonely_neighbors(to_visit, n)
            for neighbor in sorted_neighbours:
                self.tour(n+1, path, neighbor)
 
            #If we exit this loop, all neighbours failed so we reset
            self.board[to_visit[0]][to_visit[1]] = 0
            try:
                path.pop()
                print("Going back to: ", path[-1])
            except IndexError:
                print("No path found")
                sys.exit(1)
                
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Define the size of grid. We are currently solving for an 8x8 grid
 
    kt0 = KnightsTour(10, 10, fixedLocationsArray, groupsArray)
 
    kt0.tour(1, [], (3, 0))
    # kt0.tour(1, [], (7, 0))
    # kt0.tour(1, [], (7,2))
    # kt0.tour(1, [], (6,3))
    # kt0.tour(1, [], (4,3))
    # kt0.tour(1, [], (3,2))
 
    # startingPositions = [(3, 0), (7, 0), (7,2), (6,3), (4,3), (3,2)]
 
    kt0.print_board()
```

Comment: Interesting question. But you should include the problem description here, not the image.

Comment: @DanielHao done (by me for OP).

Comment: Thanks a lot for doing that for me, apologies could have laid it out clenaer the first time round - noted for next time!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some observations that you could include to be able to stop more early in your backtracking.

First of all remember that for `n` steps the total sum in all areas can be computed with the formula `n(n+1)/2`. This number has to be divisible evenly into the groups i.e. it has to be divisible by 17 which is the amount of groups.

Furthermore if we look at the 12 we can conclude that the 11 and 13 must have been in the same area so we get a lower bound on the number for each area as 2+5+8+11+12+13=51.

And lastly we have groups of size two so the largest two step numbers must make up the total sum for one group.

Using those conditions we can calculate the remaining possible amount of steps with

```
# the total sum is divisible by 17: 
# n*(n+1)/2 % 17 == 0 

# the sum for each group is at least the predictable sum for
# the biggest given group 2+5+8+11+12+13=51: 
# n*(n+1)/(2*17) >= 51

# since there are groups of two elements the sum of the biggest 
# two numbers must be as least as big as the sum for each group
# n+n-1 >= n*(n+1)/(2*17)
[n for n in range(101) if n*(n+1)/2 % 17 == 0 and n*(n+1)/(2*17) >= 51 and n+n-1 >= n*(n+1)/(2*17)]
```

giving us
`[50,51]`.
So the knight must have taken either 50 or 51 steps and the sum for each area must be either 75 or 78.